# Rspec test that service function is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service, rspec

I have a service and I want to test that a function is called.  I'm not sure how to test it because it doesn't seem like there is a `subject` that's being acted on.

```
class HubspotFormSubmissionService

    def initialize(form_data)
        @form_data = form_data
    end

    def call
        potential_client = createPotentialClient
    end

    def createPotentialClient
        p "Step 1: Attempting to save potential client to database"
    end
end
```

I want to test that `createPotentialClient` is called:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe HubspotFormSubmissionService, type: :model do
    describe '#call' do
        let(:form_data) { {
            "first_name"=>"Jeremy", 
            "message"=>"wqffew", 
            "referrer"=>"Another Client"
        } }

        it 'attempts to process the form data' do

            expect(HubspotFormSubmissionService).to receive(:createPotentialClient)

            HubspotFormSubmissionService.new(form_data).call

        end

    end
end
```

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: Why do you not want to test the actual behaviour? You should only mock dependencies of your object but not the internal behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the subject like this. Then in the test expect subject to receive the method like you have after it is mocked. I would also have a separate test for `createPotentialClient` to test that it is returning the value you expect.

```
subject { described_class.call } 

before do
  allow(described_class).to receive(:createPotentialClient)
end

it 'calls the method' do
  expect(described_class).to receive(:createPotentialClient)
  subject
end
```

Comment: When I do this I see: `Failure/Error: allow(described_class).to receive(:createPotentialClient)
       HubspotFormSubmissionService does not implement: createPotentialClient`

Comment: Nevermind, just needed to use `expect_any_instance_of`